# Найти ближайший угол к заданному

Tags: python

Пробовал несколько вариантов. Вот сама задача:

1. Есть угол ( значение может быть отрицательным и положительным)
2. Есть список с другими углами (значения могут быть отрицательными и положительными).

Необходимо найти в списке наименьший угол, ближайший к заданному углу.
Если бы углы были только положительными/отрицательными я бы быстро решил эту задачу, прошу вас помочь мне.

Comment: Что значит "больше подходить"?. И свой код приложите, хотя бы в том варианте задачи, который вы можете решить.

Comment: Какие именно проблемы создают положительные и отрицательные углы? Никакой разницы нет, хоть они только положительные, только отрицательные или же и и те и другие.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно вычесть один угол из другого и нормализовать

```
a = -14
x = [-15, 345]

n = min( x, key=lambda b : abs((a - b) % 360))
```

после abs будет всеравно в какую сторону отклонение, а получив остаток от деления на 360 будет без разницы -15 или 345

Индекс:

```
i = min(
    enumerate(x),
    key=lambda ib : abs((a - ib[1]) % 360)
)
```

Comment: На самом деле, я думал также, но почему-то у меня ничего не работало с отрицательными и положительными числами вместе, спасибо)

Comment: тут главное скобки правильно расставить)

Comment: А как получить индекс? Я конечно догадываюсь, но времени уже много потратил.

Comment: наверное есть простой способ, но в голову приходит пока только индусский))

Comment: или сделай бэйсиковски через for

Comment: Отвечу сам себе) 
s = [1,2,999,12,45]
print(s.index(999))

Comment: ну это второй проход по массиву....

Answer (score 1):

Посчитайте скалярное произведение единичных векторов, компоненты которых являются косинусом и синусом исходного угла и проверяемых углов. Наибольшее значение этой величины соответствует наиболее близкому углу.

Препод будет доволен, это не хухры-мухры со сравнением самих углов и переходом через 0 ;)

```
from math import cos, sin, radians
def closestangleidx(a, value):
    ca = cos(radians(value))
    sa = sin(radians(value))
    idx, c = max(enumerate(a), key = lambda x: ca * cos(radians(x[1])) + sa * sin(radians(x[1])))
    return idx

print(closestangleidx([-33, 90, 150, 122, 798], 45));
```

Comment: с классами и перегрузкой операторов ;)

Comment: мне  кажется   что  эти  самые  хухры  мухры со  сравнением  и  переходами  будут  работать    раз  в  500  быстрее.  чем  твой "блатной"  метод  ))

Comment: атож  тригонометрические  функции   вычислять  это  жесть

Answer (score 0):

Способ @eri мог допускать неточности. Я написал свой, хоть и больший по объему.

```
S = [95.90689155937869, 149.91173402702572, 122.17777353112672]

myangles = 220
def find(array, value):
if value <= array[0]:
    return 0
if value >= array[len(array) - 1]:
    return len(array) - 1
for i in range(len(array) - 1):
    if array[i] == value:
        return i
    if value > array[i - 1] and value < array[i]:
        if value - array[i - 1] > array[i] - value:
            return i
        else:
            return i + 1



i = find(S, myangles)
print(i)
```

Comment: А если первый элемент не минимальный, а myangles меньше его?

Comment: Согласен, это я не учел...

Comment: Какие неточности?